# Bash script to search for LDAP entries

Tags: bash, openldap

I have a bash script which is to be used to delete a particular user if it exists in a group.

First I extracted all the group names and saved it to a file. As the next step, I thought I should parse through the file, and use the ldapsearch command on all the entries and grep the user, and if it exists, use ldapmodify to delete it.

My question is how to write the if condition, i.e `if [ *ldapsearch query* == True];then`

This is what my ldapsearch looks like, and the first line inside the while loop is to be the `if` statement.

```
while read grp;do
        ldapsearch -w 'ldappass' -D "cn=adminuser,dc=some-domain,dc=com"  -b "cn=$grp,ou=group,dc=some-domain,dc=com"  | grep $someuser
done</home/someuser/tempfile.txt
```

On the CLI, this ldapsearch query returns the following output;

`memberUid: testuser`

So essentially, if the `if` statement returns some value (i.e. the user exists), then I have to delete the user. How do I get a correct `if` statement to get a True or False result for the ldapsearch query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `-z` option, that checks if the string is empty or not. `[ -z "$string" ]` is true if the string is empty. Then, this can make it:

```
if [ ! -z "$(yourcommand)" ]; then
    do_things
fi
```

For example say we want to check if a directory is empty:

```
if [ ! -z "$(ls)" ]; then
   echo "there is something"
else
   echo "this dir is empty"
fi
```

All together:

```
while IFS= read -r grp;do
   if [ ! -z "$(ldapsearch -w 'ldappass' -D "cn=adminuser,dc=some-domain,dc=com"  -b "cn=$grp,ou=group,dc=some-domain,dc=com" | grep $someuser)" ]; then
      remove $someuser
   fi
done < /home/someuser/tempfile.txt
```